# crystal report summary not working

Tags: vb.net

I have a crystal report having a running total field. 
The field data type is int32 in the dataset and have the integer values in the data set. 
I have added the running total value of the field as sum, but it only displays the number of records in the report (count of records).

How can I get the sum instead of count?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've selected `Count()` instead of `Sum()` function. Delete it and create a new one or edit the `total` field and make necessary changes.